# Where to put hardware resources in MVP

Tags: android, android-camera, android-location, android-hardware, android-mvp

I have been making an app which uses some `Android` related hardware components, like, **Microphone**, **Camera** and **Location**. I heard about **MVP** and wanted to apply it in my app, so far I have been able to separate `database` and `storage` from `activities`, but I can't understand where should I put hardware resources in `MVP`, all articles and examples tell you how to implement it but nothing came across which had used a hardware component. I was thinking if may be we have to put it outside of `MVP` and let the `Presenter` talk to them, but then they might need `android activity context`?

Comment: The hardware is also part of the Model. In case you need to interact or receive any data from the hardware you should do it in the presenter Layer and make changes to the ui according to the data.